# Живой поиск по массиву строк Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, search

Есть flask приложение.
В одном из routes мы передаём список строк.

```
dataForSearch = ['hello','world','python','hello world']

@app.route("/main")
def main():
    return render_template("main.html", title='Main', dataForSearch=dataForSearch)
```

Есть поле ввода на странице:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Поиск"/>
```

Как можно реализовать "живой" поиск, который при начале набора в поле поиска сразу же показывал выдачу результатов из переданного списка строк, используя css/javascript или как-то иначе? Среди строк должна быть возможность выбора и вставки выбора в поле ввода.

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте ajax, чтобы получать данные с сервера. Это динамическая подгрузка, по другому не получится.